# Drupal 7 form insert if already exists show message like already existed filed

Tags: mysql, drupal

```
function countries_form($form, &$form_state,$id=0) {

if($id!=0){
 $result =  db_query('SELECT * FROM {countries} WHERE id = '.$id.'')->fetch();
// print_r($result);exit;

 $form['country_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Country name',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#default_value' => $result->country_name,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Description',
    '#default_value' => $result->description,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
  $form['status'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('Status'),
  '#default_value' => $result->status,
  '#options' => array(
    '1' => t('Active'),
    '0' => t('Inactive'),

  ),
  );

  }else{
  $form['country_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Country name',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
 $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Description',
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
  }
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function countries_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
//$result =  db_query('SELECT country_name FROM {countries}')->fetch(); 
//print_r($result);
if(arg(2)!=0){

  $query = db_update('countries')->fields(array('country_name'=>$form_state['values']['country_name'],'description'=>$form_state['values']['description'],'status'=>$form_state['values']['status']))->condition('id',arg(2));

  $query->execute();
   // print_r($query); 
  drupal_set_message(t('Country %name has been updated.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['country_name'])));

  //print_r($description);
  }else{
  //$query = db_update('countries')->fields(array('country_name'=>$form_state['values']['country_name'],'description'=>$form_state['values']['description'],'status'=>$form_state['values']['status']))->condition('country_name','%s');
 // print_r($query);

  $query = db_insert('countries')->fields(array('country_name'=>$form_state['values']['country_name'],'description'=>$form_state['values']['description']));
 //print_r($query);
  $query->execute(); 

  drupal_set_message(t('Country %name has been saved.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['country_name'])));
  }

 //exit;
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'mypages/table';
  }
```

bu using druapl 7 form I am inserting and displaying date and editing and deleting as well all working fine..
now i want ..when inserting form we need to show message if already filed exists country name already taken like that..

there is not update query required only query for while inserting value check weather it is existed or not...

in that the below code is used or edit by passing arguments..

```
if(arg(2)!=0){

  $query = db_update('countries')->fields(array('country_name'=>$form_state['values']['country_name'],'description'=>$form_state['values']['description'],'status'=>$form_state['values']['status']))->condition('id',arg(2));

  $query->execute();
   // print_r($query); 
  drupal_set_message(t('Country %name has been updated.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['country_name'])));

  //print_r($description);
  }else{
```

in the else code inserting here we need to check weather existed or not

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but your writing is hard to read/understand. My English is far from perfect, but this is...

Comment: hi can you tell me how to create page template based on selection from database in drupal 7

Comment: Template for what? Page? Block? View?

Comment: I am listing data as <ul> ..now i want each list items should one url based on that url..page should be open like basic pages in drupal 7